# Migration issue from 2010 to 2013

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013

We have migrated an application from BizTalk 2010 to 2013 production.

We are getting the error below:

```
xlang/s engine event log entry: Uncaught exception (see the 'inner exception' below) has suspended an instance of service 'BizTalk.SalesForce.Integration.WebServiceServiceClient(9ee6fc07-8b64-e4cc-a2c5-710767d71ff7)'.
The service instance will remain suspended until administratively resumed or terminated.
If resumed the instance will continue from its last persisted state and may re-throw the same unexpected exception.
InstanceId: 113a84a5-d38b-4502-909e-fd3266e2d7aa
Shape name: ConstructMessage_Quote
ShapeId: 45a05a8d-0fa6-4796-8816-5ce659892091
Exception thrown from: segment 1, progress 6
Inner exception: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.EnterpriseSingleSignOn.Interop, Version=9.0.1000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Exception type: FileNotFoundException
Source: SalesForce.Integration.Login.Helper
Target Site: System.String GetSession()
The following is a stack trace that identifies the location where the exception occured
 at SalesForce.Integration.Login.Helper.ForceToken.GetSession()
 at SalesForce.Integration.Login.Helper.ForceToken.get_SessionId()
 at BizTalk.SalesForce.Integration.WebServiceServiceClient.segment1(StopConditions stopOn)
 at Microsoft.XLANGs.Core.SegmentScheduler.RunASegment(Segment s, StopConditions stopCond, Exception& exp)
```

I tried to check the GAC, the `Microsoft.EnterpriseSingleSignOn.Interop` assembly is present.

When I tried to check the `SSOMMNSnapIn.dll.config` file, it had

```
 <runtime>
   <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" appliesTo="v4.0.30319">
      <dependentAssembly>
         <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.EnterpriseSingleSignOn.Interop" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
         <bindingRedirect oldVersion="5.0.1.0" newVersion="7.0.2300.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
   </assemblyBinding>
 </runtime>
```

Even after changing the new version to 9.0.1000.0, like below it show the same error.

```
 <bindingRedirect oldVersion="5.0.1.0" newVersion="9.0.1000.0"/>
```

What should I do?

Comment: I haven't got any experience with SalesForce, but could it be that your SalesForce helper class is incompatible with this version of BizTalk?

Comment: @PieterVandenheede Thanks but what should I do now, if SalesForce Helper Class is incompatible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks the error is pretty straightforward

> Inner exception: Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.EnterpriseSingleSignOn.Interop, Version=9.0.1000.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Did you verify you have this version of this assembly deployed in your box?

**UPDATE:**

Based on this blog:
https://arcscent.wordpress.com/2014/11/12/biztalk-sso-application-configuration-setup-issue/

The Microsoft.EnterpriseSingleSignOn.Interop in Biz2013 should be 7.0.2300.0 
Version  9.0.1000.0 shipped with Biztalk 2013 R2.

Is it possible that you installed the SSO Configuration Application MMC for 2013 R2 in your old box so it have newer version, but in your new box, you did not install that.

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling Fusion log and see where the failure is happening:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Fusion
Add:
DWORD ForceLog set value to 1
DWORD LogFailures set value to 1
DWORD LogResourceBinds set value to 1
String LogPath set value to folder for logs (e.g. C:\FusionLog\)
```

Then use the fusion log viewer to find the error.

Further details:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4(v=vs.110).aspx
- http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BackToBasicsUsingFusionLogViewerToDebugObscureLoaderErrors.aspx